# Get contents source code em Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

Ola,

estou tentando utilizar um javascript para ler o código fonte de uma outra página e escrever esse conteúdo dentro de uma div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('teste.php', function(data) {
    document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML = data;        
});
</script>
```

É algo parecido com o file_get_contents do php porém em javascript

Não está funcionando... Podem me dar uma luz? Obrigado!!

Comment: tá faltando a biblioteca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Falta a biblioteca jquery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('teste.php', function(data) {
    document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML = data;        
});
 </script>

<div id="somediv"></div>
```

**Com JavaScript puro**

```
function makeHttpObject() {
  try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}

  throw new Error("Não foi possível criar o objeto de solicitação HTTP.");
}
var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("GET", "URL_da_pagina", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4)
    document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML = (request.responseText);
};
```

HTML

```
<div id="somediv"></div>
```